# Convert String to Int on AWS DocumentDB

Tags: metabase, aws-documentdb

I am currently trying to write a metabase question off AWS Document DB and I am running into an issue where I need to convert a string to an integer.  Unfortunately, it seems like aws documentdb does not support $toInt and I am not sure how to get around it.  Here is the query:

```
[
    {"$match": { 
        "metaData.fileSize" : {"$exists": true}
    }},
    {"$project": { 
        "file_size" : "$metaData.fileSize",
        "timestamp": 1,
        "past7Days": 
        { "$subtract": 
                [ ISODate(), 604800000]
        }
    }},
    {"$project": { 
        "file_size" : 1,
        "timestamp": 1,
        "dayofweek": {"$dayOfWeek":["$timestamp"]},
        "past7DaysComp": 
        { "$subtract": 
                [ "$timestamp", "$past7Days"]
        }
    }},
    {"$group" : 
            {   
                "_id" : {"dayofweek" : "$dayofweek"},
                "size": {"$avg" : "$file_size"}
            }
    }
]
```

The group returns nothing for size since it is not of a numeric type.  Any ideas how to convert file_size to integer or double or float?

Comment: DocumentDB does not support $toInt. You can try this out programmatically:

Example:
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(data) {
    db.collectionName.update({
        "_id": data._id,
        "moop": data.moop
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "PartnerID": parseInt(data.PartnerID)
        }
    });
})

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023-11-11, the `$convert` and below similar conversion aggregation APIs have become available on AWS documentDB on v4.0+, according to the [official doc from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html)

- $convert
- $toBool
- $toDate
- $toDecimal
- $toDouble
- $toInt
- $toLong
- $toObjectId
- $toString