# Document db String to Double conversion issue during aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions, aws-documentdb

I wanna use conversion operator for String to Double conversion during aggregation pipeline.

On development server I have mongodb and on prod server I have AWS document dB.

The conversion operators like $convert or $todouble works on dev server,
but failed to work on prod server due to compatibility issue.

Plz advise a solution that can work for both environments for conversion in aggregate pipeline functions.
Thanks

I was trying $convert or $todouble functions

Comment: Hard to believe, but these operators are not supported by Amazon DocumentDB, see [Type Conversion Operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#w172aac19c23c37b3). I would say, there is not simple solution, perhaps you can convert it on application side.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried for your interest.

Actually what I was trying to do is to convert a field value from string to double first and then  do a range based search by using a aggregate pipeline function.

My solution worked for mongodb by using $todouble and $convert function.
but it got stuck on AWS documentdb.

One more thing I was trying to do is to check the database first whether it is mongodb or document DB. 
And then on the bases of DB type I can use different functions in my NESTJS application.

Can you advise me a solution like that if you agree with me.

Many Thanks
Amer

Comment: The APIs are now [officially supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62032136/14732669)