# How to perform a string-to-ObjectId collection join in a DocumentDB aggregation

Tags: aws-documentdb, nosql-aggregation

We are migrating our application from Mongo 4.0 to DocumentDB 4.0 and are hampered by DocumentDB's lack of a `$toObjectId()` function.

In our application, we have two collections: person and changelog.  Example documents:

person:

```
{
  _id :      ObjectId("5a304138d9fe0b0001bdb65b"), 
  firstname: "Mike"
}
```

changelog:

```
{ 
  field:    "firstname",  
  oldValue: "Michael", 
  newValue: "Mike", 
  targetId: "5a304138d9fe0b0001bdb65b"
}
```

The `changelog.targetId` string field corresponds to the person._id `ObjectId` field.

We have an changelog aggregation that joins changelog to person using these pipeline bits:

```
{$addFields: {'personId': {$toObjectId '$targetId'}}
{$lookup: { from: 'person', localField: 'personId', foreignField: '_id', as: "joinedPerson"} }
```

However, this aggregation will not execute in DocumentDB because DocumentDb lacks the $toObjectId function:

`Command failed with error 305: 'Aggregation project operator not supported: '$toObjectId''`

**Is there any way to perform a string-to-objectId join in a DocumentDB aggregation?**

Note that a good solution will **not require any database backfills** -- we don't want to add any new fields or modify any existing fields in the database in order to get this functionality.

Comment: The APIs are now [officially supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62032136/14732669)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on DocumentDB, as [it was not possible](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781) on MongoDB prior to 4.0, before they had introduced `$toObjectId`.

Answer (score 0):

As of November 6, 2023, `$toObjectId` is now supported on both DocumentDB 4.0 and 5.0: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/release-notes.html#release-notes.11-06-2023

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer, Emmanuel!